# Partitioning a matrix into subgroup matrices

Tags: r, matrix

i have a 240 X 2 matrix and my aim is to partition it into 40 groups of 6 X 2 matrices and determine the determinants of all the Covariance matrices. i have accomplished the task with this code.

```
  mat=matrix(0,240,2)
  m=numeric()
  n=0
  for ( i in 1:40) {
      m[i]=det(cov(mat[(n+1):(n+6),]))
      n=n+6
  }
```

Is there a better way to get these determinants of the Covariance matrices and the 40 different Covariance matrices?

Answer (score 4):

**1) apply/array** Reshape into a 3 dimensional array and use `apply`:

```
apply(array(mat, c(6, 40, 2)), 2, function(x) det(cov(x)))
```

**2) rollapply**

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(mat, 6, by = 6, function(x) det(cov(x)), by.column = FALSE)
```

**3) tapply**

```
tapply(1:240, gl(40, 6), function(ix) det(cov(mat[ix, ])))
```

**4) sapply**

```
sapply(seq(1, 240, 6), function(i) det(cov(mat[i + 0:5, ])))
```

**5) for**

```
m <- numeric(40)
for(i in seq(1, 240, 6)) m[i] <- det(cov(mat[i + 0:5, ]))
```